# How to split two strings separated by a ; in two new columns

Tags: postgresql, split

So I have a command where for example

```
SELECT something, string_agg(other, ';') FROM table
GROUP BY something HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

but I don't know how to separate in two columns, because it doesn't see string_agg as a column.

This is my original

```
something | other |         
--------+--------+
 example  | yes, no   |  
 using  | why, what  |
```

and I would like this please

```
something | other | new        
--------+--------+------
 example  | yes   | no     
 using  | why     | what
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use regular expressions here:

```sql
SELECT
    something,
    SUBSTRING(other FROM '[^,]+') AS other,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(other, '.*,[ ]*', '') AS new
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would aggregate this into an array:

```
select something, 
       others[1] as other, 
       others[2] as "new"
from (
  SELECT something, array_agg(other) as others
  FROM table
  GROUP BY something 
  HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: Just use [split_part()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html) function. I combined with trim() function to remove leading/trailing spaces. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/_pmtolTT))

```
select something
     , trim(split_part(other, ',', 1)) other
     , trim(split_part(other, ',', 2)) new 
  from table;
```